# Visual Studio Crystal report

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Is there a maximum number of values that a list parameter is able to have?

My issue that i have i have a dynamic parameter that has a very long list with 50 items.

and the list of values gets cut off  when it is more than 50 items and Crystal won't import the full list. :'(  could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure about the limitations of Crystal Report, but if there is a limitation, you could add extra parameter that would filter the list to get less items than listing them all.

Answer (score 0):

See this SAP's knowledge base article on how to increase the max number of values in a dynamic parameter list: https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1218588